# Possible reading of a visually obscured word used in Indian newspaper from 1876

Tags: subcontinental-english, nineteenth-century-english

I am going through old English speaking newspapers and found the following from a newspaper called "THE PIONEER" that was published in Allahabad, India on August the 11th, 1876:

[image]

From what I can tell it reads:

> We have just learnt that a [?] took place in the Central Jail, Lahore, on the 6th instant, afternoon : one prisoner has been severely injured.

I have no idea what word *[?]* could be, any idea what it could be?

Comment: I'm guessing "fracas" from the context.

Comment: And it is italicised as *fracas* being a loan word.

Comment: Ah thank you that makes sense, I didn't know fracas could be used in this context. Looking at https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fracas gives examples like "Two people who were injured in the fracas were taken to a hospital by paramedics." The italics does also make sense since the etymology of the word appears to be Italian. Feel free to leave that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I would tidy up this question with a self answer thanks to the comments to my question.

Thanks for [@KillingTime](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/141210/Killingtime) for the suggestion of `Fracas` which was upvoted multiple times and I am happy to accept as the answer. It makes sense in the context of the sentence and the end of the word matches with the more visible characters.

Also thanks to [@Weather-Vane](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/240807/weather-vane) for pointing out the reason why the word was italicised was because it was a loan word. This also fit with the suggested word since its etymology appears to be Italian and may not be well known in India.